# text format in vc++

Tags: xml, visual-c++, string-formatting

Am trying to get the computer name, but the text am getting is not in the exact format.
My Computer Name is "text-06". But the result am getting is "ÊKÿÿÿÿ"

```
TCHAR compName[40];
if(GetComputerName(compName,(LPDWORD)&size)!=0)
  wsprintf(text,("\nComputer Name : %s "),compName);

wsprintf(text,("%s"),compName);

TiXmlText * textcompnm = new TiXmlText(text);  
elecompnm->LinkEndChild( textcompnm );
```

Comment: Does your call to GetComputerName succeed? Otherwise `text` will contain garbage. Perhaps thats what you're seeing?

Comment: yes if my computer name is set to "text", am getting the result "text"

Comment: Please clarify your question, where are you seeing the corrupt characters? With a debug watch on the `text` variable, or in the TinyXML variable?

Comment: @user1441251: so you only run into a problem if your computer name is "text-06"?  Are you setting `size` to 40 before calling `GetComputerName()`?

Comment: oh Thanks a lot. size 40 i have declared for two instinct. but it dint take the seconde size as 40. i recreated it again and now am getting the results.